g++ optimizes away check for INT_MIN in release build
I encountered a problem where g++ optimized out something it should not have. I reduced the problem to the following example:
I have a static lib with a function bool my_magic_function(int* x), which decrements x by 1 if it can, otherwise (x == INT_MIN), it returns false and does not touch the original value.
If I use the function in a debug build, then it works as expected. But in release build the check is optimized away. Platform:
On RHEL 9.3 with g++ (GCC) 11.4.1 20230605 -> Problem present
Ubuntu 22.04 g++ 11.4.0 g++ or 10.5.0 g++ -> Problem present
Ubuntu 22.04 g++ 9.5.0 -> Code works as expected in release too.
Here is a minimal example with a static lib and a simple main.cpp using the function:
almalib.h:
bool my_magic_function(int* x); 

almalib.cc:
#include "almalib.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>

bool my_magic_function(int* x) {
    int cp_new;
    // integer overflow is undefined, so lets make sure it becomes int max
    if (*x == std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()) {
        cp_new = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 
    } else {
        cp_new = *x - 1;
    }  
    if (cp_new < *x) {
        *x = cp_new;
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
} 

main.cpp
#include "almalib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    for (int x : {0, std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()})
    {
        int x2 = x;
        std::cerr << "Res for " << x << " " << (my_magic_function(&x2) ? "OK" : "NOT_OK") << " val: " << x2 << std::endl;
    }
}

Compile:
g++ -c almalib.cc -o almalib.o
ar crf libalma.a almalib.o
g++ main.cpp -o run -L. -lalma

g++ -c almalib.cc -O3 -o almalibR.o
ar crf libalmaR.a almalibR.o
g++ main.cpp -O3 -o runR -L. -lalmaR

outout for Debug (./run):
Res for 0 OK val: -1
Res for -2147483648 NOT_OK val: -2147483648

output for Release (./runR):
Res for 0 OK val: -1
Res for -2147483648 OK val: 2147483647

going through the generated assembly with gdb, my_magic_function is reduced to 3 lines:
0x401320 <_Z17my_magic_functionPi>      subl   $0x1,(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                                          
0x401323 <_Z17my_magic_functionPi+3>    mov    $0x1,%eax                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0x401328 <_Z17my_magic_functionPi+8>    ret               

My questions are:

Is this a known issue?
What are my options to prevent it from happening? (I can trivially rewrite the example function, but not the original problem). Are there any compiler hints, or should I disable a certain optimization type?


Looks like an bug introduced in gcc-10 and fixed in gcc-12, but I can't locate the right ticket. Reproduction on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vhTPEPz8c

Required reading: Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)

Tried out on godbolt. Can't reproduce the problem. Your given compilers return expected results...

@MarkRansom can you point at undefined behaviour in posted code?

@ÖöTiib if I could, I'd leave an answer instead of a comment.  But the article is still full of examples of how compilers can rearrange sensible code into nonsense with optimization.

@MarkRansom it's indeed a great article, but all the cases there are the result of underfined behavior which we can pinpoint in the code. Do you think this is the case here ? I admit I failed to spot one.

@wohlstad I failed to spot one too, but undefined behavior can be extremely subtle!  It sure seems like a possibility though based on the symptoms.

@MarkRansom The other possibility is a compiler bug, especially given that gcc-9 is correct, gcc-10 is wrong, gcc-11 is wrong and gcc-12 and up is correct again.

It appears the answers to your questions are:  yes this is a known issue, and upgrade your compiler.

Thank you all for the help. However, not being compatible with g++ 10 and 11 is not a small limitation. Actually, not being compatible with the default g++ on many currently used Linux distributions is not something I would consider as a solution.

I mean, https://godbolt.org/z/az13dWWYx doesn't have the bug and is logically identical.  As a guess, the compiler is noticing that your max test does not change the value of cp_new - the branches are identical.  So it optimizes it out.  Then it does cp_new < *x where cp_new = *x-1 and says "underflow is UB, so we can ignore it", thus the answer is always true: it uses known-result UB to optimize, then uses the fact that one branch is UB to optimize again (in error).  My version tests for the failure explicitly instead.

@MarkRansom: Using constexpr disallows most UB, and they all accept the code Demo. So the buggy ones have runtime values which differ from compile time values.

These can be expensive, but -fwrapv and -ftrapv both make your problem evaporate.
-fwrapv means that the compiler assumes signed integers act like unsigned integers and wrap around.  This is what your hardware almost certainly does.  -ftrapv means it adds traps (exceptions) for when signed integers wrap around (you can probably set flags on your hardware to get this to happen, if not it will add in logic to catch it).
With either flag, your code acts correctly.
While -fwrapv seems harmless, what it means is that a bunch of optimizations in loops and comparisons cannot be done.
Without -fwrapv, the compiler can assume a+b with both greater than 0 is greater than a and greater than b.  With it, it cannot.
As a guess, your compiler is first taking the early branch code
if (*x == std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()) {
    cp_new = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 
} else {
    cp_new = *x - 1;
}

and saying "on the hardware target, this is equivalent to"
cp_new = *x - 1;

because it knows the hardware target has signed underflow that wraps around.  Significant optimization, eliminates a needless branch!
It then looks at
if (cp_new < *x) {
    *x = cp_new;
    return true;    
}

then replaces cp_new:
if ((*x - 1)< *x) {
    *x = (*x - 1);
    return true;    
}

and reasons "well, signed underflow is undefined behavior, so something minus 1 is always less than something".  Thus optimizing it into:
*x = *x-1;
return true;    

the error being that it used cp_new = *x - 1 in a context where underflow is defined and wraps around first, then reused it without allowing for the wrap around case.
By making underflow cause a trap or making it assumed to be true, we block the assumptions that let it do the 2nd false optimization.
But this story - why fwrapv/ftrapv work - is a "just so story", it is not informed by actually reading the gcc code or bug reports; it is a guess I made as to the cause of the bug, which led to the idea of messing with the overflow settings, which did fix your symptoms.  Consider it a fairy tale explaining why -fwrapv fixes your bug.

This can't be correct; the compiler can't optimize the branching away arguing that it's the same on the target architecture, thereby introducing undefined behavior, and then using that justification to optimize more code away. I expect it's simply a compiler bug.

@ShdNx Yes, it is a compiler bug.  It is fixed in gcc 12.  The OP knows it is a bug as well, this is about fixing the problem without updating the compiler.  I am simply giving a fairy-tale explanation of what the bug could be and why changing overflow flags seems to fix it.
